# How did Tusk survive the bombing?

Tags: cross-ange

How the hell did Tusk live through that bombing in episode 21? He is the person that the bomb was closet to since it was on his person, so how is it possible that he lived?

Comment: Fukuda tweeted something relevant at https://twitter.com/fukuda320/status/571725677088489472, but he must've deleted the tweet at some point, and the Wayback Machine isn't currently able to load its archived version of the page. Once the archive comes back up, I can probably answer this question.

Comment: I found [someone who had quoted Fukuda's tweet](http://blog.goo.ne.jp/cobra007/c/901de17e9a5add1a157982ac5ab1083d). For posterity: 「規制された部分のコンテです。タスクが体にC4巻いていたという所。爆弾を見せないから、何故あそこで爆発があったか判らなかったし、あれじゃあタスクが生きてることになってしまう。酷いセンスだ…。そもそもこれ、規制必要か？#クロスアンジュ 」. Unfortunately, it is not as relevant to your question as I remember it being; it's basically Fukuda griping about how the actual explosion was censored / discretion-shot'ed. This may remain a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but I would say he actually died. However, because Ange wanted him to live so much, her ragna-mail brought him back to life.

(After all, it could merge worlds and travel between them, who's to say it couldn't bring Tusk back.)

Answer (score 0):

I’ve read many ideas regarding how Tusk & Momoka survived without a scratch, as well as somehow appearing on the same island as Ange without any delay or notice - my first thought (& Ange even stated her suspicions) was that Embryo was trying to trick her.

I believe that Embryo decided to take over Tusk's body after he died - which makes perfect sense since Ange willingly took the initiative to sleep with him which is what he wanted all this time. And so he decides to play the part of the hero from here on in, deceiving everyone & even killing his original plan of world destruction or whatever it was. Booya! Embryo wins, happy ending for him! God is certainly a deceptive being - do not mess with him, you can’t ever win it seems…